# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' - when communication is established between models.Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

In my application I use two models and between them is one to one:

```
relationship:db.relationship('Operation',uselist=False, backref='operat')
```

Below are the models themselves.

```
class Operation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "operation"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)    
    date_operation = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True)
    code = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    status_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    status = db.Column(db.String(60))
    type_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    type = db.Column(db.String(120))
    storage_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    storage = db.Column(db.String(240))
    contragent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contragent.id'))
    contragent = db.Column(db.String(240))
    sum_operation = db.Column(db.Integer)
    rezerv = db.Column(db.Integer)
    cnt_doc = db.Column(db.Integer)
    stellag = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Operation {}>'.format(self.code)


class Contragent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "contragent"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(360))
    code = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    adress = db.Column(db.String(480))
    inn = db.Column(db.Integer)
    operations = db.relationship('Operation',uselist=False, backref='operat')


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Contragent {}>'.format(self.name)
```

When selecting records and getting the name of records to the referenced model `p.operat.name`

```
>>> o = Operation.query.all()
>>> for p in o:
...     print(p.id, p.operat.name, p.code)
...
2 Рога и копытца22sdsd 222
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
>>>
```

What causes the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Check your Operation entity attributes list. ```operat``` is in that list?

Comment: `contragent_id` is nullable => `p.operat` may be `None`.

Comment: @Victor Ruiz No, the operat attribute is not listed since the second entry. With that in the first record this attribute is present, in all subsequent ones there is no

Comment: I really had entries with no value in the 'contragent_id' field, so an error occurred. But how to make it so that the 'contragent_id' field is optional and there was no error?

Comment: Your comment is not related with the error you wrote. In your post, you tried to access the attribute ```operat``` on Operation object (inside the loop). And that attribute is ```None```